# How can display a FloatField in a Django admin column rounded to the nearest integer, without using a custom list_display?

Tags: django, django-admin

It would be easy with a custom list_display, but that would cause me to lose the sorting ability according to that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say this:

> However, if an element of list_display represents a certain database field, you can indicate this fact by setting the admin_order_field attribute of the item.

So you should define your function to display the rounded value, but set admin_order_field to preserve the ordering capability.